# menu's position for responsive site

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have to do a website with a central DIV ( which is a menu ) and a cross as background. When the user come on the site, the cross as to be centered, so I used

```
"background-position:50% 50%;"
```

Which works well.
The problem is that when I click on various menus, the cross'center have to go on borders. When the user click on the right image, the cross'center must go on the right border of the screen, and same for top, botom and left images.

I would like to avoid to fix the MAIN's size, to use % instead, but when I do this, it is impossible to center the cross'middle on borders correctly ( it moves and so the positionning becomes wrong ).

Here is an link for view image to show it better:
[image here](http://sdz-upload.s3.amazonaws.com/prod/upload/menu30.png)

Note that the cross'image is 3000x3000px large.
Do anyone have an idea to implement this?

Here is my HTML :

```
<div id="main">
   <div class="menuLosange">
    <div class="losange" id="menuHaut"></div>
    <div class="losange" id="menuBas"></div>
    <div class="losange" id="menuDroite"></div>
    <div class="losange" id="menuGauche"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And Here is my CSS :

```
body {  
    width:100%;  
    margin:auto;  
    padding:10px;  
}


#mainLeft {  
    display: inline-block;  
    width: 20%;  
    vertical-align: top;  
    padding-top:20px;  
    font-family: verdana;     
}

#main {  
    display: inline-block;  
    width:79%;      
    background-color:#E6E6E6;  
    height:900px;  
    background-image: url('images/background2.png');  
    background-position:50% 50%;  
    overflow:hidden;  
}
```

Thanks for responses.

Comment: if it's only me that unclear about the question?

Comment: take the blue pill my friend :)

Comment: @Emin You also took that?

Comment: @C-link that was not ment for you! The OA could not express his actual problem due to his poor english, which sometimes I also have difficulties when asking questions. When there are such cases, I always spend some time to prepare a fiddle link (taking the red pill) because I do not want the audience to also spend time to fix my grammer and "guess" what I actually mean by my question.